# How to fix error add user on remote machine with ssh

Tags: linux, shell

I am having a problem. I have 2 servers 10.84.70.132 and 10.74.70.131, on each server there are 2 similar scripts, `a.sh` and `main.sh`. `a.sh` is responsible for adding a user and giving ownership of that user to a directory, `main.sh` will run `a.sh` locally and `a.sh` on the remote

**Content of a.sh**

```
mkdir -p $2
useradd $1
chown $1 $2
```

**Content of main.sh**

```
a.sh "alex" "/opt/test"
echo $password | sshpass -p $password ssh -tt $user@$remote "sudo bash a.sh alex /opt/test"
```

However when I run on server 10.84.70.131 user alex is created on both servers with id=1010 but the directory /opt/test is owned by user alex, and on server 10.84.70.132 is owned by user 1010

Comment: If you run in server131 how it can create in server132? Could you explain better how are you reaching the servers? Are you using ssh? please elaborate

Comment: I am using ssh to server 132 and running a.sh on server 132